# How to display XCB window's name in Gnome's alt-tab view?

Tags: c, gnome, xcb

I have a simple XCB window. When I run my application and <kbd>alt-tab</kbd>, Gnome's window list displays my application as "unknown". The window's title bar shows the correct title.

Here's how I set its title:

```
xcb_change_property(WindowGlobal::connection,
                    XCB_PROP_MODE_REPLACE,
                    WindowGlobal::window,
                    XCB_ATOM_WM_NAME,
                    XCB_ATOM_STRING,
                    8,
                    strlen (title),
                    title );
```

Here's most of my window creation code:

```
int visualID = screen->root_visual;

xcb_colormap_t colormap = xcb_generate_id( connection );
WindowGlobal::window = xcb_generate_id( connection );

WindowGlobal::windowWidth = width == 0 ? screen->width_in_pixels : width;
WindowGlobal::windowHeight = height == 0 ? screen->height_in_pixels : height;

xcb_create_colormap( connection, XCB_COLORMAP_ALLOC_NONE, colormap, screen->root, visualID );

const uint32_t eventmask = XCB_EVENT_MASK_EXPOSURE | XCB_EVENT_MASK_KEY_PRESS | XCB_EVENT_MASK_KEY_RELEASE |
                           XCB_EVENT_MASK_BUTTON_PRESS | XCB_EVENT_MASK_BUTTON_RELEASE | XCB_EVENT_MASK_POINTER_MOTION;
const uint32_t valuelist[] = { eventmask, colormap, 0 };
const uint32_t valuemask = XCB_CW_EVENT_MASK | XCB_CW_COLORMAP;

xcb_create_window(
                  connection,
                  XCB_COPY_FROM_PARENT,
                  WindowGlobal::window,
                  screen->root,
                  0, 0,
                  WindowGlobal::windowWidth, WindowGlobal::windowHeight,
                  0,
                  XCB_WINDOW_CLASS_INPUT_OUTPUT,
                  visualID,
                  valuemask,
                  valuelist
                  );

xcb_map_window( connection, WindowGlobal::window );

xcb_size_hints_t hints = {};

xcb_icccm_size_hints_set_min_size( &hints, WindowGlobal::windowWidth, WindowGlobal::windowHeight );
xcb_icccm_size_hints_set_max_size( &hints, WindowGlobal::windowWidth, WindowGlobal::windowHeight );

xcb_icccm_set_wm_size_hints( WindowGlobal::connection, WindowGlobal::window, XCB_ATOM_WM_NORMAL_HINTS, &hints );

xcb_atom_t protocols[] =
{
    WindowGlobal::wm_delete_window
};
xcb_icccm_set_wm_protocols( WindowGlobal::connection, WindowGlobal::window,
                            WindowGlobal::wm_protocols, 1, protocols );
```

How do I make XCB to set the text that shows in Gnome's window list?

Comment: I don't know what Gnome uses, but did you try setting `_NET_WM_NAME` (with type `UTF8_STRING`) instead of or in addition to `WM_NAME` (with type `STRING`)?  `WM_NAME` is older than UTF8, so a new property had to be invented for UTF8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right property in xcb is `XCB_ATOM_WM_CLASS`.

I have seen some code on GitHub, where two strings were being concatenated with a `"\0"`.
*(I saw it in [awesomeWM/awesome/xwindow.h](https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/blob/6f047e946851a3a3c8aa37008c079873291e683a/xwindow.h#L51) and other window managers on GitHub)*

This worked for me:

```
xcb_change_property(WindowGlobal::connection,
                    XCB_PROP_MODE_REPLACE,
                    WindowGlobal::window,
                    XCB_ATOM_WM_CLASS,
                    XCB_ATOM_STRING,
                    8,
                    sizeof("title""\0""Title"),
                    "title\0Title" );
```

The second part of the string is what is shown in gnome.

Here is another common way I have seen:

```
char *res_name = "title";
char *res_class = "Title";

char *class_hint;
size_t class_len;
class_len = strlen(res_name) + 1 + strlen(res_class) + 1;
class_hint = (char *)malloc(class_len);
strcpy(class_hint, res_name);
strcpy(class_hint + strlen(res_name) + 1, res_class);

xcb_change_property (WindowGlobal::connection,
                     XCB_PROP_MODE_REPLACE,
                     WindowGlobal::window,
                     XCB_ATOM_WM_CLASS,
                     XCB_ATOM_STRING,
                     8,
                     class_len,
                     class_hint);

free(class_hint);
```

The `char *res_class` is what is shown in gnome.

With Xlib you would use the function `XSetClassHint`.
There you would use the `XClassHint` struct which consists of two strings:
`char *res_name` and `char *res_class`.

On https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/man/man3/XAllocClassHint.3.xhtml I found this:

> The res_name member contains the application name, and the res_class member contains the application class. Note that the name set in this property may differ from the name set as WM_NAME. That is, WM_NAME specifies what should be displayed in the title bar and, therefore, can contain temporal information (for example, the name of a file currently in an editor’s buffer). On the other hand, the name specified as part of WM_CLASS is the formal name of the application that should be used when retrieving the application’s resources from the resource database.

I could find more information [here](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man3/XSetClassHint.3.html) and [here](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man3/XClassHint.3.html).